# CustomView Not Supporting Rtl

Tags: android-custom-view, right-to-left

I'm using https://github.com/InQBarna/TableFixHeaders library as my CustomView.

But this library not supporting Rtl. How can i achieve Rtl support for this CustomView?

Comment: did you find any solutions?

Comment: I got solution.

Comment: will you like to share actually I am having the same problem with other another library but hope it may be some thing general

Comment: I just rotate the root layout and gesture scrolling actions